# How to create clone of tr and insert data in new row using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr id="rptShippinRates_ctl01_A" class="row">
  <td>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" id="hdnSupplierShippingID" value="28">
    </div>
    <div class="gvColSet tLightBlack gvColAlignLeft" style="font-size: 12px;" title="Test1">Test1</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="gvColSet tLightBlack gvColAlignLeft" style="font-size: 12px;" title="$ 10.00">$ 10.00</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span id="SpnDeleteShipping" class="DelRow" title="Delete shipping rate" style="float: Left;margin-left: 8px;"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to clone of this using JavaScript or jQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What data do you want to insert? Where does it come from? On what event do you wish to clone the row? Where, if anywhere, do you want to append it?

Comment: and what have you tried

Comment: Note that if you directly copy the markup, character for character, you will need to change the `id` on the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr id="rptShippinRates_ctl01_A" class="row">
<td>
       <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hdnSupplierShippingID" value="28">
       </div>
       <div class="gvColSet tLightBlack gvColAlignLeft" style="font-size: 12px;" title="Test1">Test1</div>
  </td>
<td>
     <div class="gvColSet tLightBlack gvColAlignLeft" style="font-size: 12px;" title="$ 10.00">$ 10.00
     </div>
     </td>
<td>
   <span id="SpnDeleteShipping" class="DelRow" title="Delete shipping rate" style="float: Left;margin-left: 8px;"></span>
   </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
$('tr').clone().appendTo('table');
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P8Tkf/
also you have to remove ids, because id must be unique.

Comment: how can I insert data in place of Test1 and $10.00 using your code I have this data in hiddenfilds

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tr = $('tr.row'); // fidn the row you want to work with

$tr // grab the row
  .clone() // clone it
  .prop('id','...') // change its id
  .find('td:eq(0)') // find the first <td>
    .find('input') // find hidden input
      .val('...') // change its value
    .end()
    .find('.gvColSet') // find the nested gvColSet
      .text('...') // change its text
      .prop('title','...') // and change its title
    .end()
  .end()
  .find('td:eq(1)') // find second <td>
    .find('.gvColSet') // find the nested gvColSet
      .text('...') // change its text
      .prop('title','...') // and its title
    .end()
  .end()
  .appendTo($tr.closest('table')); // append it to the same table
```